# Killing thread from another thread c++

Tags: c++, multithreading

I am new to multithreading and i need your help.
Consider the following code:

```
vector <int> vec; 
int j = 0;
void Fill()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    {
        Sleep(500);
        vec.push_back(i);
    }

}


void Proces()
{
    int count = 0;
    int n=-1;
    while (true) {
        Sleep(250);
        if (!vec.empty())
        {
            if (n != vec.back()) {
                n = vec.back();
                cout << n;
                count++;
            }
        }
        if (count == 101)break;
    }
}

void getinput()
{
    while (true) {
        int k=0;
        cin >> k;

            //if the user enters an integer i want to kill all the threads
    }
}
int main()
{
    thread t1(Fill);
    thread t2(Proces);
    thread t3(getinput);
    t1.join();
    t2.join();
    t3.join();
    cout << "From main()";


}
```

The point is that i want to kill t1(Fill) and t2(Proces) from t3(getinput).Is there and way to do it,and if there is could you please post and example.

Comment: You cannot use a `std::vector` this way from multiple threads without synchronization (by `std::mutex`). As for "killing", you can use, e.g., an `std::atomic<bool>` variable, which would be set in `t3` and checked in `t1` and `t2`.

Comment: Just "killing" a thread is usually bad. A better solution is to ask the thread to exit, through an atomic flag that the tread checks regularly.

Comment: @DanielLangr the point is that i have to check the vector if there is any input and if there is i have to do something with it

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude how could i ask the thread to exit ?

Comment: @J.Rusev This does not change anything. `std::vector` is generally not _thread-safe_.

Comment: @DanielLangr which container is the best solution when working with threads ?

Comment: @J.Rusev No container in STL is thread-safe, as far as I know. Just use `std::mutex` with `std::lock_guard` to protect access to your vector.

Answer (score 3):

A common way to make a thread exit is to have an ([atomic](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/atomic/atomic)) flag that the thread checks to see if it should exit. Then externally you set this flag and the thread will notice it and exit naturally.

Something like

```
#include <thread>
#include <atomic>
#include <iostream>
#include <chrono>

// Flag telling the thread to continue or exit
std::atomic<bool> exit_thread_flag{false};

void thread_function()
{
    // Loop while flag if not set
    while (!exit_thread_flag)
    {
        std::cout << "Hello from thread\n";
        std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(1));  // Sleep for one second
    }
}

int main()
{
    std::thread t{thread_function};  // Create and start the thread
    std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::seconds(5));  // Sleep for five seconds
    exit_thread_flag = true;  // Tell thread to exit
    t.join();  // Wait for thread to exit
}
```

Comment: Rather than put scare quotes around "kill", you should reinforce the idea that threads always need to _cooperate_ with one each other.  One should not think about killing a thread: One should think about politely asking the thread to clean up and stop.

Comment: @jameslarge Good idea, reworded answer.

Comment: How can a thread notice if the flag changed if it's blocked in a `recv`?

Comment: @CristianTraìna Use non-blocking sockets and polling of the sockets?

Comment: Should not this flag be volatile?

Answer (score 2):

You have to define an exit condition and lock the container before accessing it. Of course you could build an own collection as wrapper around an existing using proper locking and thus making it thread-safe.

Here is an example of locking and an exit condition:

```
class Test
{
public:
    Test()
        : exitCondition(false)
    {
        work = std::thread([this]() { DoWork(); });
    }

    ~Test()
    {
        if (work.joinable())
            work.join();
    }

    void Add(int i)
    {
        mutex.lock();
        things.push_back(i);
        mutex.unlock();
    }

    void RequestStop(bool waitForExit = false)
    {
        exitCondition.exchange(true);
        if (waitForExit)
            work.join();
    }

private:
    void DoWork()
    {
        while (!exitCondition)
        {
            mutex.lock();
            if (!things.empty())
            {
                for (auto itr = things.begin(); itr != things.end();)
                    itr = things.erase(itr);
            }
            std::this_thread::sleep_for(std::chrono::milliseconds(1));
            mutex.unlock();
        }
    }

private:
    std::vector<int> things;

    std::thread work;
    std::atomic<bool> exitCondition;
    std::mutex mutex;
};

int wmain(int, wchar_t**)
{
    Test t;
    t.Add(1);
    t.Add(2);
    t.Add(3);

    t.RequestStop(true);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
std::atomic<bool> exit_flag{false};
...
void Fill() {
   for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++) {
      if (exit_flag) return;
      ...
   }
}

void Proces() {
   while (true) {
      if (exit_flag) return;
      ...
   }
}

void getinput() {
   while (true) {
      ...
      if ( /* the user enters an integer i want to kill all the threads */ )
         exit_flag = true;
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the example ! Helped me a lot.